# How can I view Dart global variables in the WebStorm debugger?

Tags: dart, webstorm

Consider this Dart CLI program:

```
int result = 42;

main() {
  print('Result: $result');
  ++result;
  print('New result: $result');
}
```

`result` is a global variable.  If I set a breakpoint in `main()`, I would expect to see `result` somewhere in WebStorm's debugger window.  However, I don't:

[image]

Is it possible to view global variables in the debugger?

Comment: You can try adding them as watch expression on the right in the window that your screenshot shows, or use them in the location where you set the breakpoint. If you have `print(myGlobal)`, then you should be able to see the value of `myGlobal`. Currently Dart doesn't include the whole possible scope into the current stack for debugging, only what is actually used.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer if you put this in an answer, I'll mark it correct.